# Codeigniter - Hashtag not working in views

Tags: php, codeigniter

The hashtags `#profile` for example is not working in codeigniter.

My view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">User</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#edit-profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Edit User</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#my-posts" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Entries</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="profile">
            ///mystuffhere
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="edit-profile'>
            ///mystuffhere
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="my-posts'>
           ///mystuffhere
       </div>
```

However, I have a pagination feature which doesn't let me use the href feature very well. I have no idea how to put `#profile` after the url because the url is something like `http://localhost/admin/page/`. Since there are no `.html, php` extentions, I don't know how to do it. I can't put it like `http://localhost/admin/page/#profile` or `http://localhost/admin/page#profile/` either. Please help. Thanks

Comment: This is for my pagination: `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/users/edit/$uid/#profile";`  But that clrealy doesn't work.

Comment: You're trying to set your base url to that? Sounds like what you're looking for is routes. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: So basically, you'd make a function in admin as `users($uid, $variable)` and a route that was `$route["admin/users/edit/(:num)/(:any)"] = "admin/users/edit/$1/$2"` and then use the passed in  to do whatever logic you need

Comment: why cant your url be something like this: `www.test.com/controller/method#profile` ?

Comment: It doesn't really work like that. 
I have tried: `http://localhost/users/edit/1/#settings` where `1` is the user id but no luck. I have even tried `http://localhost/users/edit#settings/1/` but nothing.